# Serverless: Importing file to custom + other variables

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have a `serverless.common.yml`, with properties that should be shared by all the services, with that:

```
service: ixxxx
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  resourcesStages:
    prod: prod
    dev: dev
  resourcesStage: ${self:custom.resourcesStages.${self:custom.stage}, self:custom.resourcesStages.dev}

lambdaPolicyXRay:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - xray:PutTraceSegments
    - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
  Resource: "*"
```

And, another `serverless.yml` inside a services folder, which uses properties on the common file:

```
...

custom: ${file(../../serverless.common.yml):custom}
...
environment:
    stage: ${self:custom.stage}
...
```

In that way, I can access the custom variables (from the common file) without a problem.
Now, I want to continue to import this file to custom, but adding new variables, related to this service, to it, so I tried that:

```
custom: 
  common: ${file(../../serverless.common.yml):custom}
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

And it seems it's possible to access, for example:

```
environment:
    stage: ${self:custom.common.stage}
```

But now, I'm receiving the error:

```
 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid service attribute to satisfy the declaration 'self:custom.stage' could not be found.


 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid service attribute to satisfy the declaration 'self:custom.stage' could not be found.


  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${self:custom.stage}. Please make sure the value of the property is a strin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `serverless.common.yml` you must reference as if it were `serverless.yml`. In this case `${self:custom.stage}` does not exist, but `${self:custom.common.stage}` does exist.

```yaml
service: ixxxx
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  resourcesStages:
    prod: prod
    dev: dev
  resourcesStage: ${self:custom.common.resourcesStages.${self:custom.common.stage}, self:custom.resourcesStages.dev}

lambdaPolicyXRay:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - xray:PutTraceSegments
    - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
  Resource: "*"
```